# Can't Add New Page or New Post

Tags: wordpress

Currently moved a website from one domain to another
Everything works except the add new page and new post and also can't edit prevoius post

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBcae.png)

Currently running on wordpress 4.9.1
Disabled all plugins

And from the error image above, can write in title section but cant for the body part

Help would be pretty much appreciated

Comment: You should give more information if you want someone to reply to you , with only that info i don't think nobody is gonna be able to help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's going to be nearly impossible for anyone to help without more information - what theme are you using?

Comment: KICKCUBE - Membership & User Content Sharing Theme

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clear your browser's cache and cookies?

If your browser google chrome:

1. Ctrl+H
2. Click clear browsing data
3. Click tab advanced -> time range (All times)
4. Check all the box
5. Clear data

Reference:
Based on experience (Google chrome)

Comment: No but I tried mozilla firefox and still getting the same problem